# Variable substitution/expansion - safe way in perl

Tags: perl, code-injection, substitution

I need one very simple line-based (space delimited) "language", what in general will look for some predefined "actions" (1st field), and execute defined perl subs with the arguments (other fields in the line).

one of many actions is "define variable value" what should be usable in the next actions.

fragment of the code (input is in the **DATA**):

```
use 5.012;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $VARS;
while(my $line = <DATA>) {
    chomp $line;
    next unless ($line =~ m/^\s*(def|echo|SOME|OTHER|ACTIONS|HERE)\s+(.*)/ );
    my $action = $1;
    my $args = $2;
    my(@fld) = split /\s+/, $args;
    for ($action) {
        when (/^def$/) { $VARS->{$fld[0]} = expandvars($fld[1]); } #expand and store
        when (/^echo$/) { say expandvars($args); }  #echo
    }
    #say Dumper($VARS);
}

sub expandvars {
    my($str) = @_;
    if( $str =~ /\$\{(\w+?)\}/ ) {
        ##############################################
        #is this SAFE or Dangerous? 
        $str =~ s/\$\{(\w+?)\}/$VARS->{$1}/xeg;
        ##############################################
    }
    return $str;
}
__DATA__
#"action" define aaa
def aaa somestring

#define bbb
def bbb ===${aaa}===

#echo 
echo this is ${bbb} here

#here will continue another "actions", but they're
#not needed for the question
```

The program is working (probably far from "optimal"), gives the wanted result

```
this is ===somestring=== here
```

but my question is:

Is the way how i substituting the variable **SAFE**? So, if the user will give some other lines (the program will read them from stdin) is possible to construct *some dangerous things*? Is the above way *reasonable safe* for variable expansion? Or if it is wrong, where I can learn the right way? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An attacker would have to put characters in that either close brackets or open new ones. If you narrow it to word characters, I don't see how it can be not safe.

Incidentally, you can speed up your regex by making the capture expression a solid `+` for the variable name. If you run into a close-curly, you will not consume it with a `\w` having been specified.

```
s/\$\{(\w+)\}/$VARS->{$1}/xeg;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is safe in the sense that I can see no way for injection attacks. However, this isn't an especially well-designed templating language:

```
def .   invisible
def var no-vars-with spaces
echo ${.}
echo ${var}
```

should output

```
${.}
no-vars-with
```

Your code could probably be factored better, but that is largely irrelevant.

The `/e` flag on your substitution does nothing in this case: There is effectively no difference between `qq/$var/` and `$var`.